# Nodejs is installed but not NPM

Tags: npm

I have installed nodejs on ubuntu 15.10 :

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

npm should come with nodejs but when I do `npm -v`, it says that it is not installed.
So I have tried to install it :

```
sudo apt-get install npm
```

but I am getting :

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  npm : Depends: nodejs
>   but it is not going to be installed
>          Depends: nodejs-dev
>          Depends: node-request but it is not going to be installed
>          Depends: node-mkdirp but it is not going to be installed
>          Depends: node-minimatch but it is not going to be installed
>          Depends: node-semver but it is not going to be installed
>          Depends: node-ini but it is not going to be installed
>          Depends: node-graceful-fs but it is not going to be installed
>          Depends: node-abbrev but it is not going to be installed
>          Depends: node-nopt but it is not going to be installed
>          Depends: node-fstream but it is not going to be installed
>          Depends: node-rimraf but it is not going to be installed
>          Depends: node-tar but it is not going to be installed
>          Depends: node-which but it is not going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

If anyone knows how to solve this,...

Thank you

Comment: Does Node work correctly?

Comment: when I do nodejs -v I am getting 0.12.12

Comment: This is very old version of Node. Install latest instead.

Comment: I know there is a 4.x version, but it appears that 0.12.12 is the latest one, I don't know what are the differences between these two versions naming.

Comment: what about use nvm? https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try to

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall nodejs
```

and post any errors and/or version of nodejs after reinstall.